# Why PowerShell does not run my script from a C# app?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-4.8

I'm writing a C# program that runs PowerShell scripts.

Scripts could be anything, the user select the one to run.

Problem here is that some scripts do not run.

This is the method I use:

```
private void runScript(String path)
        {
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "powershell.exe",
                Arguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File \"{path}\"",
                UseShellExecute = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };
            Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
```

The function works but for example I got a script that use:

```
$CurrentSiteURL = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/$SelectedCompany"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $CurrentSiteURL -Credentials $global:credentials
$FolderPath = $global:userPath + $SelectedCompany
$InvoiceFolders = Get-ChildItem $FolderPath
```

That is just a fragment but specially with this script the app does not run anything.

The script code is all ok because if I run it manually, it works.

Any ideas?

I tried this but Invoke() does not support user interaction and some script need that.

```
public static void runScript(string script)
        {
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);
            pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();
        }
```

Comment: The powershell executable is not on the standard PATH environmental doesn't include path where powershell is located.  Try C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Comment: Is perhaps the `$global` scope the problem?

Comment: I tried what @jdweng suggest but not works.
I meant that the script does nothing. $global is not the problem.
As I mentioned, if I open a new Powershell window and run the script it'll success.
But when running from the app nothing happens.

If I set to open a new PowerShell windows within my C# app when running a script, this happen:
It wait for (supposedly) end the execution of script and then show this:
C:\Users\marco\InvoiceUploader>

But if withing the same PS window I do this:
C:\InvoiceUploader> c:\InvoiceUploader\script.ps1
When i hit enter, the script runs as usual.

Comment: Maybe script is closing at end.  Try adding following to end : Read-Host "End of Script, Press Return"

Comment: Yes, I know that.
I actually want the script to run in background and just add -NoExit for debug and see what is happening.
Problem here is that any line of code runs. i.e.  test.ps1: cp c:\file.txt c:\copy.txt That is a very simple script. When i run from the app the file isnt copied, in other words the script execute nothing.
-ExecutionPolicy is set to Bypass as well.
I really have no idea what is the error.